# How to validate the answer to a random Math equation in ASP.NET MVC forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have recently seen some sites that ask you to "*prove you are not a robot*" by solving a Math equation, instead of using something like [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)...

I am trying to take that idea a step further by randomly generating a simple Math equation, with a single operator and two operands, and requiring the user to solve the equation before submitting a form:

[image]

Here is my model:

```
public class ContactModel
{
     public string Expression;
     public static string AnswerToExpression;

     [Required]
     // compile-error on this line! see bottom of question...
     [RegularExpression(ContactModel.AnswerToExpression.ToString())]
     public string AnswerField { get; set; }

     public ContactModel()
     {
         this.Expression = this.GetRandomExpression();
         AnswerToExpression = this.GetAnswerFromExpression(this.Expression);
     }

    private string GetRandomExpression()
    {
        Random rand = new Random(); // using only one instance for unique numbers
        return rand.Next(1, 10).ToString() + " * " + rand.Next(1, 10).ToString();
    }

    private int GetAnswerFromExpression(string expr)
    {
        // splitting by a "char space":
        string[] tokens = expr.Split(' ');
        return Int16.Parse(tokens[0]) * Int16.Parse(tokens[2]);
    }
}
```

...the relevant view code:

```
@model MyWebsite.Models.ContactModel

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <span>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnswerField, Model.Expression + " = ")</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AnswerField, new { @placeholder = "answer to " + Model.Expression + "..." })
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" title="submit your message" />
    }
```

...and the relevant controller code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ContactModel model = new ContactModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(ContactModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // insert into database, send email, etc..

            // redirecting to the home page here:
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            // staying on the contact page if the form does not validate:
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

So when trying to pass a static variable into `RegularExpression`, I am getting the compile-error "***An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.***"

Do I need to create a custom class that extends from `RegularExpressionAttribute` and use that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass a constant as a param to attribute. This means that your param value has to be defined during the compilation, in your case the param will only be defined at runtime.

If you try `[RegularExpression("MY_EXPRESSION")]` no compilation error will occur.

[Attribute Usage Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664613%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) should help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @CoffeeCode! I didn't like this answer at first ha, and struggled to find a way around it... After being unsuccessful, in the process I learned a lot about the purposeful restrictions of `const` formal-parameters. So is the constructor of `RegularExpression` defined with a `typeof` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

@CoffeeCode is correct, and so I have a javascript / jQuery solution:

First I have made this change in my model:

```
// this is now an instance variable:
public string AnswerToExpression;
```

...and I have added the js to a section reference I named `"Scripts"` in my view:

```
@model MyWebsite.Models.ContactModel

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("form").submit(function () {
            var answerField = $("#answer");

            // comparing the user's answer to the model variable here:
            if (answerField.val() !== "@Model.AnswerToExpression") {
                alert("Incorrect answer!");

                // preventing the form from being submitted here:
                return false;
            }
        }); // end of form submit
    </script>
}

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <span>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnswerField, Model.Expression + " = ")</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AnswerField, new {
            @placeholder = "answer to " + Model.Expression + "...",
            // added this id for javascript use:
            @id = "answer"
        })
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" title="submit your message" />
    }
```

...where `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)` is placed at the bottom of my `_Layout.cshtml` file, before the closing `</body>` tag (*this is where the javascript embedded in my view is placed*).